# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %

Tags: jquery, django, static

I receive the error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %"

Below is the is the component/templates/component/update.html template which is defined as:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %} 

{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'component/js/component.js' %}"></script>

<h2>Create new component</h2>

{% include 'snippets/form-snippet.html' with form=form %}

{% endblock %}
```

I have the script saved at component/static/component/js/component.js. The file is found since in the console.log i can read: "GIVE ME SOME LOG". However I receive the error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %" The component.js file is defined as follows:

```
console.log("GIVE ME SOME LOG")

$(document).ready(function(){
    hideShow()
})

$('#id_component_type').click(function(){
    hideShow()
});

function hideShow(){
  if(document.getElementById('id_component_type').options[document.getElementById('id_component_type').selectedIndex].value == "k_v")
    {
        $('#id_length').parents('p:first').hide();
        $('#id_k_v').parents('p:first').show();
    }else
    {
        $('#id_length').parents('p:first').show();
        $('#id_k_v').parents('p:first').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using Django template tags in a static file?

Comment: So I should remove the {% block jquery %} ... {% endblock %} tags in the jquery_script.js file, but it's still not working. What am I doing wrong? Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the script location. you have given component/js/jquery_script.js

```
<script src="{% static 'MyApp/js/jquery_script.js' %}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your static files are in directory like: `MyApp/static/MyApp/js/jquery_script.js`
Then You can write

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'MyApp/js/jquery_script.js' %}"></script>
```

Here, `{% static ...` static means, the static folder location, by default it's the `AppFolder/static/` folder which can be set from `settings.py`

For details visit: [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial06/#customize-your-app-s-look-and-feel)